# Android - Set ImageView to URL

Tags: java, android, url, bitmap, imageview

I am trying to set an Imageview to a URL.

Below is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.getpic);
    ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivget);

    URL url;
    try {

        url = new URL("http://0-media-cdn.foolz.us/ffuuka/board/sp/thumb/1359/41/1359419073599s.jpg");
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        i.setImageBitmap(image);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But whenever I try to open/run the app it crashes, why isnt it working?

```
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  instantiate activity  ComponentInfo{com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy/com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.Practice2}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
 06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.Practice2.<init>(Practice2.java:17)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
06-15 00:37:20.977: E/AndroidRuntime(8579):     ... 11 more
```

above is the logcat, I am not sure where the error is in it specificaly though..............................................................................................................................................................

Comment: are you using asynctask? post the stack trace?

Comment: include logcat error here

Comment: include the whole code looks like one of the views is not initialized

Comment: @rahulkapoor I added the logcat error

Comment: have you initialize your imageview.??

Comment: have you set proper layoutview ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android

Comment: @user222786 try the below answer it works

Comment: @user222786 did you try the below?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not do network related operation on the main ui thread.

You can findViewById of the current view hierachy set to the activity. check if you have imageview in ivget.xml. Also use a asynctask as below and make a http get request to get the image.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="173dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class AndroidCustomGalleryActivity extends Activity { 
ImageView iv;
Bitmap image ;
ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setMessage("Loading..");
    new TheTask().execute();    
}
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        //URL url = new URL( "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png");


        image = downloadBitmap("http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo-v3-twitter.png");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
        if(image!=null)
        {
            iv.setImageBitmap(image);
        }

    }   
}
 private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
     // initilize the default HTTP client object
     final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

     //forming a HttoGet request 
     final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
     try {

         HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

         //check 200 OK for success
         final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

         if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
             Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + 
                     " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
             return null;

         }

         final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
         if (entity != null) {
             InputStream inputStream = null;
             try {
                 // getting contents from the stream 
                 inputStream = entity.getContent();

                 // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
                 image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


             } finally {
                 if (inputStream != null) {
                     inputStream.close();
                 }
                 entity.consumeContent();
             }
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
         getRequest.abort();
         Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
                 " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
     } 

     return image;
 }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
```

=> It says you haven't initialized your ImageView i.e. "i" in your code.

```
ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageViewInXML);
```

Comment: @user222786 where have you written this code of fetching image from web and setting to ImageView?

Comment: you should use a asynctask you cannot do network related operation on the main ui thread

Answer (score 0):

Use Glide

Implementation `'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'`

Or

in java

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(image)
                .into(imageView);
```