# how to parse .gif or .jpg image from json object and show in listview

Tags: android

have a json object with a tag image having images with .gif extnsion..how can i parse them & show in my list view..

```
 {

    "Image": "no_image.gif",
 }
```

I have got string values through

```
image=c1.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
```

next what should be done???

Comment: use image loader for that..

Comment: need urgent hlp..any1 plz..

Comment: You will have to make a http get request and then display the iamge

Comment: image loder????  did'nt got u... @Segi

Comment: any link or example would hlp.. @Raghunandan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120230/android-set-imageview-to-url/17120523#17120523.  what is this `no_image.gif`. this is name i guess not a url. where is your image url?

Comment: thats d prblm..i dont have the url jst a Image tag with image "no_image.gif"

Comment: you need the url or the path of the image. where does this `no_image.gif`reside on the server sdcard?

Comment: how can i get that url/path??? @Raghunandan

Comment: without path how you can show the image in listview or any other view.

Comment: get it from your json. how would i know whether your json has a url or not?

Comment: http://test.onlineordering.com.au/mobile/webservice.asmx/AdvancedSearch?login=2ecVGZvUMmGFz8eWbSMUGA%3d%3d&password=uddPTuwHBSHR6crss%2f%2bWrw%3d%3d&id=1&supplierId=5&categoryID=101&productCode=&productName=&productDesc=&brand=&supplierName=

Comment: above is my url for json.. @Raghunandan

Comment: the link does not have any image url.

Comment: http://test.onlineordering.com.au/pictures/Trollplast/no_image.gif

Comment: above is the path of my image..NO IMAGE is actually the image..@Raghunandan

Comment: solved it with using Lazy adapter.