# Update Pictures on ImageView from online

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview, updates

How is it possible to update pictures live on an app, doing it all from online? Like iFunny, Cyanide & Happiness, Instagram they update picture on a regular basis and i want to know how to do this on my app as well?

I would like to get information from a server, and the app would be able to make a new imageView for it and post it

Thank you for any help you can provide :) 
(I am a newbie, sorry if this question sounds stupid).

Comment: See this (found by googling "android imageview from url"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120230/android-set-imageview-to-url

Comment: please update your question, based on your requirement, then surely you will get meaningful answers.

Comment: Yeah, but i would want to update the picture and change it without recoding that specific section of the app
Thank you for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ton of different ways to do this, all depending on your needs and requirements. You can have your app poll data from a server, or you can have the server notify the client using Google Messaging for Android, or something else. Cant say for sure how the apps you mention do it specifically as I dont use any of them myself, but maybe someone else here knows.

Comment: How would an app poll data from a server? I was aiming for that but could not find much tutorials for it online

Thank you, and the username Zygotes pretty bomb.

Comment: Again, there are so many ways of doing it, and probably many that are better than how I would do it. However, personally, depending on how you've designed your app, you could have a simple web server that you communicate with using JSON. So say, you write a method in your app called "getNewPics()" which asks the server for new pictures. The server returns JSON items with URLS for pictures you then load up in your app. Makes sense? Oh, and thanks! Im an Android nerd so Zygote made sense to me ;)

Comment: I get you, im going try it out and use JSON.
Thank you! :D

Comment: Good luck! Its pretty smooth and simple :) About to embark on a large JSON-based project myself so feel free to let me know how it works out for you ;)