# how to display image and questions using asynctask for flag quiz game

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, android-imageview

I want to bring image and text   contents for flag quiz online database after long search i found [this](http://www.trickey.tk/2016/03/android-quiz-app-mysql-json-php-studio.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120230/android-set-imageview-to-url) that use asyncTask concept as guide for the task and  i have managed to create below code that bring all  requred questions and answers but it does not display corresponding image, so  based on my codes: 
1. Where do i get it wrong ?
2. How can i fix it so that my codes  can work(display image and text).?
  please help me to finish this assignment

```
     public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
    quizQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quiz_question);
    AsyncJsonObject asyncObject = new AsyncJsonObject();
    asyncObject.execute("");
         }

   private class AsyncJsonObject extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>        {
             private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
            @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");
        String jsonResult = "";
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            System.out.println("Returned Json object " + jsonResult.toString());
        }
        catch (

                ClientProtocolException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResult;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        parsedObject = returnParsedJsonObject(result);
        if(parsedObject == null){
            return;
        }
        quizCount = parsedObject.size();
        firstQuestion = parsedObject.get(0);
        quizQuestion.setText(firstQuestion.getQuestion());
        String[] possibleAnswers = firstQuestion.getAnswers().plit(",");
        optionOne.setText(possibleAnswers[0]);s
        optionTwo.setText(possibleAnswers[1]);
       image= downloadBitmap(firstQuestion.getImageUrl());
        if(image!=null)
        {
            pic.setImageBitmap(image);
        }
           }
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
     } }
       // Get JsonObject 
    private List<QuizWrapper> returnParsedJsonObject(String result){
    List<QuizWrapper> jsonObject = new ArrayList<QuizWrapper>();
    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    QuizWrapper newItemObject = null;
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        System.out.println("Testing the water " + resultObject.toString());
        jsonArray = resultObject.optJSONArray("quiz");
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = null;
        try {
            jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = jsonChildNode.getInt("id");
            String question = jsonChildNode.getString("question");
            String answerOptions = jsonChildNode.getString("possible_answers");
            int correctAnswer = jsonChildNode.getInt("correct_answer");
            String image_url = jsonChildNode.getString("image_url");
           newItemObject = new  QuizWrapper(image_url,id, question, answerOptions, correctAnswer);
            jsonObject.add(newItemObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } }
    return jsonObject;}
// processing image url to get an Image
private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    // initilize the default HTTP client object
    final DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    //forming a HttoGet request
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        //check 200 OK for success
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                    " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;
        }
        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                // getting contents from the stream
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // decoding stream data back into image Bitmap that android understands
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // You Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.e("ImageDownloader", "Something went wrong while" +
                " retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
    }

    return image;
}
```